# Questiones in combine cmakelist project to Ros system

Tags: cmake, ros

My project is written in `Cmakelist.test` and I want to configer it to Ros system so that I can also use the beautiful topic and subscribe function. But after I read through the **Ros tutorial**, it makes me a little confused is that Ros use `catkinmake.list` while cmakelist is already there in my project. My point is should I add something into my `Cmakelist` so that it will fit in with Ros or should I write a `catkinmakelist` and How can I make it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's better if you write another one. The point is that a ROS package comes with a CMakeLists.txt(http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and a package.xml (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml) which are both necessary, and if you are familiar enough to write your own CMakeLists, the Catkin one uses almost the same logic so you won't get surprised.

Also, you have to specify your package architecture (msg, srv, nodes...) and then tune the xml and the Lists file to include your dependencies and libraries...

Hope this helps !
Cheers,